# How to enforce a person to use the type of data type while declaration using swiftlint

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swiftlint

I'm trying to enforce my team to use data type when declairing a var/let
Instead of var name = "john"
I want var name: String = "john"

Can anyone name the rule of swiftLint to implement this change?

Comment: Please don't do that to your team 

Comment: There is a bigger power above me who is making me do this 

Comment: You should probably remind them what type of language Swift is - the types are [inferred](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID322), and unnecessarily adding types like this is just clutter. I don't know how to enforce this in SwiftLint, but it's probably for the better if the rule doesn't exist :p It's not like there will be issues where if a value is changed (so the underlying type changes), everything breaks - the variable still has a specific type. It's not JavaScript, the compiler will complain about type errors.

Comment: Just throwing something out there. I have reduced compile times significantly by declaring type vs letting it be inferred. If you add  `-Xfrontend -warn-long-expression-type-checking=200 -Xfrontend -warn-long-function-bodies=200` to "Other Swift Flags" in Build Settings you will see where you can benefit from it. It is definitely a preference thing and it does look more cluttered but in large projects it can make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

In the .yml file add this rule "explicit_type_interface"